# Missing package dependencies in Google's Drive API - name 'drive_service' is not defined

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I try to connect Python with the Google Drive following [this introduction](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder).

Unfortunately, the dependencies seem to be missing to execute the following code

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'Invoices',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Does anybody know, from where I need to import `drive_service`?

Answer (score 2):

`drive_service` is not a module to import, but is an object you build with credentials and scopes using the google-api-python-client in this case. It is through that authorized `drive_service` that you can make calls to Drive API.

In the quickstart here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python you can see how to import the `build` function to create the service, as well as the pip command to install the client library.

So in your example you could build a Drive service with the following command. Do have a go at the quickstart guide referenced above.

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```